# relationship and blade in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have 3 table as mentioned below.

```
Table 1(user): 
id    username   password  Name Age

Table 2(tasks):
id  task_name  description

Table 3(logs) 
id user_id task_id date hours
```

**Table Relationships:**

```
user has_many logs
task has_many logs

logs belongs_to user 
logs belongs_to  task
```

what i am trying to achieve is to get the logs with the user Name, task Name, date and hours.

**Controller:**

```
return View::make('log.index')
            ->with('logs',log::all());
```

**Blade template**

```
@foreach($logs as $log)
             <tr>
                <td>{{$log->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$log->users()->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$log->tasks()->name}}</td>
            <tr>
@endforeach
```

but unable to fetch users Name and Tasks name from the respective table. any help is appreciated.

Comment: `{{$log->users()->name}}` How do you expect multiple users to have a single name?

Comment: @WaleedKhan i am new to laravel i was just trying that out but didnt work. tried this too {{$log->users(user_id)->name}}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A better way is to define inverse hasMany relation in your Model, as documented [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

So in your logs model, probably you need to define:

```
class Log extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "logs";

    public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function task(){
         return $this->belongsTo('Task');
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can either use :

```
$log->user()->first()->name
```

or even better, by using Dynamic Properties:

```
$log->user->name
```

Comment: `$log->user()->first()->name` this will leads to N+1 problem.

Answer (score 9):

$log->users() and $log->tasks() returns a query object. Below, each call returns the result which is the same as calling $log->users()->get() and $log->tasks()->get(). Because the relationships are many to many, you'll need to iterate over $log->users and $log->tasks to retrieve each record.

```
@foreach($logs as $log)
         <tr>
            <td>{{$log->id}}</td>
            <td>
                @foreach($log->users as $user)
                {{$user->name}},
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach($log->tasks as $task)
                {{$task->name}},
                @endforeach
            </td>
        <tr>
@endforeach
```

If you want a specific user/task attached to a log you'll have to build a query.

```
@foreach($logs as $log)
         <tr>
            <td>{{$log->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$log->users()->where('id', '=', $userID)->first()->name}} </td>
            <td>{{$log->tasks()->where('id', '=', $taskID)->first()->name}} </td>
        <tr>
@endforeach
```