# Laravel, how to show a related table's associated name in my home.blade.php?

Tags: php, laravel

I know the question might be unclear, but let me elaborate. I have a home page for my website (home.blade.php), where I list the items like this.

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="m-auto text-center">
        <h2>
            <a href="/products/{{ $product->id }}">
                {{ $product->name }}
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p>
            Manufacturer: {{ $product->manufacturer }}
        </p>
        <p>
            Price: {{ $product->price }}
        </p>
        <p>
            In stock: {{ $product->stock }}
        </p>
        <a href="seller/{{ $product->sellerID }}">
            Seller's site
        </a>
        <hr>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I want to show the name attribute of my seller table instead of the Seller's site. With the product table, it's in a many-many relationship. And I store a sellerID attribute in my product table as a foreign key, which references the seller's table id attribute. As for my HomeController.php, the function currently passing the values looks like this.

```php
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('home', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

I know that I shouldn't do a query in any view, but I can't figure out how I should do the query in the controller. Can someone help me with this?
Also, please ignore the bad-looking site, I'm currently trying to do the backend first, and the frontend comes later.

Comment: Hi, you need you check out relation on Laravel 
in short 
Product::with('seller')->get();
 in long 
Class Product .....

 public function sellers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Seller::class, "seller_product");
    }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [relationship and blade in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480510/relationship-and-blade-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you entirely, because I got confused.

If you have many-to-many relationship, you can't have sellerID. Foreing id can be used in one-to-many or one-to-one relationships.

In order to have many-to-many relationship, you need to have a pivot table.

```
product_seller
id, product_id, seller_id
```

In conttoller

```
Product::with('sellers')->get();
```

In view, there is another problem. You will have many sellers, but you want to display only one, which one? I assume you either have a wrong relationship, or wrong view, or misexplained problem. But if I go based on many to many:

```
@foreach ($product->sellers as $seller)
    <a href="seller/{{ $seller->id }}">Seller's site</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: If I get the pivot table, then I'll be able to get the seller's id only, but I need the name of his.

Comment: First thing first, there is no such thing as many-to-many without pivot table. Also, if you query 'sellers' it returns seller models not only ids.

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve it thanks to your help, sorry for not being professional enough, I'm new here.